# Encode E-Mail in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, email, encode

I have a page who i can see all user profiles.
So i have a foreach who show me all my profiles.

i want to display the user email

this is the way i do:

```
<a href="mailto:{{$user->email}}">{{$user->email}}</a>
```

but i want to encode the mailto because i want to prevent spam mails

so i want it like:

```
<a href="&#109;&#097;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#058;&#109;&#097;&#105;&#108;&#064;&#101;&#120;&#097;&#109;&#112;&#108;&#101;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;">
```

instead of

```
<a href="mailto:mail@example.com"><mail@example.com</a>
```

does anyone know how i can do this in laravel?

because there is a tool like this:http://www.wbwip.com/wbw/emailencoder.html

but here i can only encode one email

is there a way in laravel who i can say encode($user->email) and then i have the mail like on the top??

thank you so much!

i searched everywhere but i can not find anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
{!! link_to("mailto:".$user->email, $user->email) !!}
```

Comment: it says undefined function link_to ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you need is `htmlentities` in php

> htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: but this is php syntax and i need laravel syntax?

Comment: laravel is a php framework, so you can use that in laravel :)

Comment: i tried it but it only convert html so like you can see it here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp 

buti want it like here: https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-to-html-entities

they call it html entities also but i dont know how he do this?